# Bind object to element attribute in vue.js

Tags: javascript, binding, vue.js

Consider

```
<ul>
  <li v-for="o in objects" v-on:click="click"></li>
</ul>
```

where objects in something like

```
var objects = [
    { derp: 1 },
    { derp: 2 },
];
```

in my `click()` function, I want to get access to `o` instance.

```
function click(event) {
    console.log(event.target.myObject);
}

<li v-for="o in objects" v-on:click="click" v-bind:data-myObject="o"></li>
```

and then getting the object using `event.target.getAttribute("data-myObject")` yields a `string`, not `object`.

I can make this work using an index, and then lookup the object from `this.$data.objects[index]`. This seems backward to me, as I expect some way of binding  `o` instance to the target generated `<li>` element.

How to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass object in calling function as in below example

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el:'#app',
  data:{
    myObj: [
      { derp: 1 },
      { derp: 2 },
    ],
    output:''
  },
  methods:{
    myFunc: function(obj){
      this.output = obj;
      console.log(obj);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="o in myObj" v-on:click="myFunc(o)">{{o.derp}}</li>
  </ul>
  {{output}}
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! That's it :)